# Times font in math with LuaLatex

Tags: math-mode, luatex

Is there a "short and clean" way to get Times font in math while using LuaLatex?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}  % This does not work with LuaLatex
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
$X_\text{testing}=Y^2+5$, $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{y}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\setmathfont{XITS Math}` or `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}` or, if you installed the STIX Two fonts, `\setmathfont{STIX Math Two}`. Of course you need also Times for text.

Comment: @egreg: I have tried the `\setmathfont` solutions you suggested but LaTeX cannot recognize the command. Is there a package I need to `\usepackage` first?

Comment: Yes, sorry: you also have to load `unicode-math`.

Comment: @egreg: It worked. Gives a warning: `Package amsmath Warning: Unable to redefine math accent \mathring.` Could you please make an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure `lualatex-math` really adds benefits, but it doesn't harm, either.

In order to better use math in LuaLaTeX, you can add `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{lualatex-math}

\setmainfont{STIX Two Text}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}


\begin{document}

Some text to show that a clone of Times New Roman is used
\[
X_{\textnormal{testing}}=Y^2+5, \qquad \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{y}}
\]

\end{document}
```

There are other choices, for instance

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
```

The STIX Two fonts are available at [STIXFonts.org](http://www.stixfonts.org), whereas TeX Gyre Termes is included in the main TeX distributions.

[image]

A couple of notes:

- `amsmath` should be loaded ahead of `unicode-math`
- the correct syntax for a textual subscript is `X_{\textnormal{word}}`, because `\text` would select the same font as the text surrounding the math; for a single word, it's even better to use `\mathrm`; note the additional braces.